# How does rails choose which version of an instance variable to render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm fairly new to rails & I'm trying to understand why rails chooses one version of an instance variable over another.

In the controller I have my instance variables defined.

```
def show
    @discussions = Discussion.all.order('created_at desc')
  end

 def new
    @discussion = current_user.discussions.build
  end
```

If I were to call @discussion in one of my views, which version of the variable would it choose?

Comment: It is determined by which controller action is currently being called/used.

Comment: So if I'm in the show.html.erb view that would call/use the def show version of the instance variable correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: What do you mean, "what version"? Those are different variables, with different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each action in the controller (`show` and `new`) correspond to and render views with the same name. So, your `show` method in the controller renders `app/views/controller_name/show.html.erb`, unless you tell it otherwise by calling `render` explicitly.

The only instance variables available to `show.html.erb` are the ones defined in the `show` action of the controller. The same goes for other actions.

Comment: The first paragraph is roughly correct. The second paragraph less so. If, in the `new` action, one were to call `render :show`, then `show.html.erb` would have access to the instance variables declared in the `new` action, not the `show` action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to rails, but let me take a crack. I think in both cases, @discussion will be the same thing, the one which it is assigned to. So in your code snippet, **if you make a GET call to /controller_route/new** it will show you exactly what you intended - `current_user.discussions.build`.

If you make a GET call to `/controller_route`, it will be `nil`, since you haven't defined it. `@discussions` has no bearing on the evaluation.

But again this is my guess; Would be glad to be educated/corrected on this.

Comment: As far as I understand your wording, you got it right.

Comment: Good to know @SergioTulentsev. Thanks.